# Having problems with code "plot_2d_classification"

Tags: python, plot

I am working my way through the online text "Applied Machine Learning in Python" at https://amueller.github.io/aml/01-ml-workflow/02-supervised-learning.html
Currently, I am working through the chapter on "Supervised Learning". The following snippet of code occurs toward the end of the chapter:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
for ax, n_neighbors in zip(axes.ravel(), [3, 5, 11, 33]):
    ax.set_title(f"n_neighbors={n_neighbors}")
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors).fit(X_train[['mean compactness', 'worst concave points']], y_train)
    ax.scatter(X_train['mean compactness'], X_train['worst concave points'], c=y_train, cmap='bwr', s=2)
    plot_2d_classification(clf, np.array(X_train[['mean compactness', 'worst concave points']]), ax=ax, alpha=.4, cmap='bwr')
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    ax.set_xlim(0.05, 0.17)
    ax.set_ylim(0.06, 0.2)
```

When I copy and paste it into Jupyter Notebook, it returns the following error:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 2>()
4 clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors).fit(X_train[['mean compactness', 'worst concave points']], y_train)
5 ax.scatter(X_train['mean compactness'], X_train['worst concave points'], c=y_train, cmap='bwr', s=2)
6 plot_2d_classification(clf, np.array(X_train[['mean compactness', 'worst concave points']]), ax=ax, alpha=.4, cmap='bwr')
7 ax.set_aspect("equal")
8 ax.set_xlim(0.05, 0.17)

NameError: name 'plot_2d_classification' is not defined

It is supposed to return a set of the following four plots.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1VPT.png)

I have done a Google search  using the term "plot_2d_classification" and received a single page of links, none of which provide any insight.

I found the following two posts by A. Mueller for

plot_2d_separator.py https://github.com/amueller/mglearn/blob/master/mglearn/plot_2d_separator.py

which requires

plot_helpers.py https://github.com/amueller/mglearn/blob/master/mglearn/plot_helpers.py

Cutting and Pasting the snippet of code above returns additional errors such that none of the three sets of code runs successfully.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you didn't define the function `plot_2d_classification`
Just copy the function `plot_2d_classification` in the [plot_2d_separator.py](https://%20https://github.com/amueller/mglearn/blob/master/mglearn/plot_2d_separator.py) and make a little modification. The full codes:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier


def plot_2d_classification(classifier, X, fill=False, ax=None, eps=None,
                           alpha=1, cm=''):
    # multiclass
    if eps is None:
        eps = X.std() / 2.

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - eps, X[:, 0].max() + eps
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - eps, X[:, 1].max() + eps
    xx = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 1000)
    yy = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 1000)

    X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
    X_grid = np.c_[X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]
    decision_values = classifier.predict(X_grid)
    ax.imshow(decision_values.reshape(X1.shape), extent=(x_min, x_max,
                                                         y_min, y_max),
              aspect='auto', origin='lower', alpha=alpha, cmap=cm)
    ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
    ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())


cancer = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True)
cancer_df = cancer.frame

data_train, data_test = train_test_split(cancer_df)


X_train = data_train.drop(columns='target')
y_train = data_train.target
X_test = data_test.drop(columns='target')
y_test = data_test.target



fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
for ax, n_neighbors in zip(axes.ravel(), [3, 5, 11, 33]):
    ax.set_title(f"n_neighbors={n_neighbors}")
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors).fit(X_train[['mean compactness', 'worst concave points']], y_train)
    ax.scatter(X_train['mean compactness'], X_train['worst concave points'], c=y_train, cmap='bwr', s=2)
    plot_2d_classification(clf, np.array(X_train[['mean compactness', 'worst concave points']]), ax=ax, alpha=.4, cm='bwr')
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    ax.set_xlim(0.05, 0.17)
    ax.set_ylim(0.06, 0.2)
```

Then run the code, you'll get the figure:

[image: Figure you want]

Comment: I followed your suggestion with the following error:

NameError: name 'xx' is not defined

So, as per your lead, I added the rest of the code, as below:

def plot_2d_classification(classifier, X, fill=False, ax=None, eps=None,
                           alpha=1, cm=cm3):
    # multiclass
    if eps is None:
        eps = X.std() / 2.

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - eps, X[:, 0].max() + eps
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - eps, X[:, 1].max() + eps
    xx = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 1000)
    yy = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 1000)

Comment: HMH1013 - your suggestion was invaluable. I really like how you turned it into a pipeline. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Copy the full codes in the answer, save it in a file `xxx.py`, then run the file.